# Two Existing Numpy Arrays, Conditionally Filling in NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For each component in a large dataset, I have two equally-shaped numpy arrays: raw data, and artifact data, stored in a pandas dataframe like so:

```
sub run1 ... run4
0 [data, art] ... [data, art]
1 [data, art] ... [data, art]
2 [data, art] ... [data, art]
3 [data, art] ... [data, art]
4 [data, art] ... [data, art]
```

For example: subject 1 run 1 has

```
data([[104.,  96.,  94., ...,  99.,  99.,  96.],
       [102.,  94.,  92., ..., 100.,  99.,  97.],
       [101.,  93.,  91., ...,  98.,  98.,  96.],
       ...,
       [ -8.,  -5., -12., ...,  -9.,   3.,  10.],
       [ -8.,  -5., -13., ..., -10.,   4.,  11.],
       [ -9.,  -5., -13., ..., -10.,   5.,  13.]])
```

and

```
artifact([[2., 2., 2., ..., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., ..., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., ..., 2., 2., 2.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

When a value in the artifact array is not 0, I'd like to replace the corresponding location in the data array with NaN. This could be done in place or in a new array. Each run is not necessarily the same length between subjects.

Comment: In numpy it is quite simple: `data[artifact == 0] = np.nan`.

Comment: Using the following, I'm getting an error that the object is not subscriptable. 
```
for sub in subs:
   for run in runs:
      df.loc[sub][run][data][df.loc[sub][run][art] == 0] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

Using loops in Pandas (like Clayton's answer does) gives poor performance and makes code harder to read. Whenever possible, let Pandas handle the iteration for you, like this:

```
def replace_values(item):
    """Operate on a single DataFrame cell
    """
    data = item[0]
    artifact = item[1]
    data[artifact == 0] = np.nan
    return [data, artifact]

df.applymap(replace_values)
```

This is an important practical and methodological point. One of the key selling points of Pandas, on a basic level, is that it includes many functions that handle complex operations, saving you the trouble of writing iterating control structures,  and running faster to boot.

Methodologically speaking, these "bundled" operations save you from having to think about the details. In plain English, my solution says, "Here is a function that operates on a cell. Apply it to each cell." It's concise and obvious at a glance, as long as you know what `applymap` does. You don't have to read through the explicit looping syntax to figure out what's going on.

Yes, there's a bit of a learning curve, but it's worth it.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: I actually read the guidelines before posting, because I was wondering the same thing, but nowhere in the guidelines does it say that you should provide an explanation.

Comment: Check out [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation) for some reference. We don’t vote to delete code only answers, and instead add a comment asking for more explanation. More is always better.

Comment: Btw this is a good answer and point about loops. You can’t vote in review but I voted now.

Comment: Could you provide more info on implementation? I don't follow the comment on operation of a single dataframe cell in this context. Wouldn't you still have to loop over the dataframe, then apply this function?

Comment: No, you don't. The single call to ```df.applymap``` takes care of it all for you. I added a more detailed explanation above.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your suggestions. I think I found a workaround implementing numpy masks like so.

```
import numpy.ma as ma

def artifactEEG(df):
    for sub in df.index.values:
        for run in df.columns:
             mx = ma.masked_array(df.loc[sub][run][0], mask=df.loc[sub][run][1])
             df.loc[sub][run][0] = mx
    return(df)
```